# How to merge diff result between two files into a third file?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a Perl script that will do the following:
compare two files with the same name from different source dirs, meaning:

```
diff source_dir_1/file_1 source_dir_2/files_2
```

and for each changed line in file_2 (compared to file_1) it will find the line from file_1 (that has been changed in file_2) at a third file: source_dir_3/file_3, and replace this line with the line from file_2.

For example, for:

**file_1:**

> My name is Shahar
>   Hello World
>   Nice to meet

**file_2**

> My name is Shahar
>   Goodbye World
>   Nice to meet

**file_3:**

> This line can be different
>   Hello World
>   Nice to meet

The resulting file_3 will be:

**file_3_after_script:**

> This line can be different
>   Goodbye World
>   Nice to meet

I'm having a problem with writing it, because sometime one line in file_1 will be replaced with several lines in file_2,

Do you have any suggestions about how I should approach this problem?

Comment: Your description is unclear. The first line is the same in file_1 and file_2, yet you still replace it with the line from line_3.

Comment: You may find [Algorithm::Diff](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Diff) useful.

Comment: Sounds like a [three way merge](https://www.google.no/search?q=three+way+merge) issue. Try google and see if the problem is already solved with other tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal is unclear.  Always include the code that you've tried in any question on SO.

Nevertheless, it is of course possible to open 3 files simultaneously and perform logic on them.

The following shows my best interpretation of your goal.  It cycles through the lines of each file, and prints the line from file2 if file1 and 2 different, otherwise prints file3.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file1 = '...';
my $file2 = '...';
my $file3 = '...';

#open my $fh1, '<', $file1;
#open my $fh2, '<', $file2;
#open my $fh3, '<', $file3;
# Open to strings temporarily to make script self-contained:
open my $fh1, '<', \ "My name is Shahar\nHello World\nNice to meet\n";
open my $fh2, '<', \ "My name is Shahar\nGoodbye World\nNice to meet\n";
open my $fh3, '<', \ "This line can be different\nHello World\nNice to meet\n";

while (! grep eof $_, $fh1, $fh2, $fh3) {
    my $line1 = <$fh1>;
    my $line2 = <$fh2>;
    my $line3 = <$fh3>;

    print $line1 ne $line2 ? "file2: $line2" : "file3: $line3";
}

print "file3: $_" while (<$fh3>); # Print rest of file (if any)
```

Outputs:

```
file3: This line can be different
file2: Goodbye World
file3: Nice to meet
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
open (file1,'file_1');
open (file2,'file_2');
open (file3,'file_3');
@f1= <file1>;
@f2 = <file2>;
@f3 = <file3>;
print "$f3[0]\n$f2[1]\n$f1[2]\n";
```

This also gives outputs which you tries.

Comment: thank you I've used the previouse suggestion and it was helpfull